# Make a 2D list from a user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

I want to make a list of lists. It must be able to catch the user input and store it as a list inside a list. Something like:

The user passes values like:

```
5 4

1 2

3 4

4 5

1 3
```

So I take the user input and store it as a list inside a list. It would be like

```
lis2 = [[5, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5], [1, 3]]
```

So I did something like this

```
edges = [ ]

for k in range(m): #m is the no of edges
    edges.append([int(i),int(j)] for i,j in [input().split(" ")])
```

I get a list of generator objects:

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fb3d04f38e0>, <generator object 
<genexpr> at 0x7fb3d04d0f10>, <generator object <genexpr> at 
0x7fb3cf034f68>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fb3cf034fc0>]
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in  python 3 it will return as generator so you need to use list to parse values, `list(generator objects)`

By the way,

simple example in  python3,

```
edges = []
for _ in range(5):
    edges.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
print(edges)

mohideen@dev:~$ python3 Desktop/sample.py 
1 2
2 3
3 4 
4 5
5 6
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
mohideen@dev:~$
```